# Atualizar automaticamente o timestamp no update

Tags: mysql

Utilizando o `UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` é possível atualizar automaticamente um campo de uma tabela no banco de dados MySQL?

Quero que na inclusão, a data da inclusão seja atribuída aos campos: `dt_cadastro` e `dt_atualizacao`.

E quando for realizada uma alteração, o campo `dt_atualizacao` seja atualizado com a data da modificação.

Segue minha tabela:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_devedor`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_devedor` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `sistema` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `id_assessoria` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `dt_cadastro` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `dt_atualizacao` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `situacao` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

Comment: cria uma trigger pra disparar `update tbl_devedor set dt_atualizacao = current_timestamp where id = new.id;`

Comment: Está dando algum erro atualmente?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Erro não dá, mas não está atualizando.

Comment: Qual instrução SQL utilizou para fazer o UPDATE?

Answer (score 5):

Altera na criação da tabela para:

```
`dt_atualizacao` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

e veja se funciona.

Comment: Não funciona, já havia tentado desta forma.

Comment: Esta é a solução adequada. O problema é se o autor estiver usando um MySQL desatualizado (o que parece ser o caso), aí só a primeira coluna timestamp é que vai funcionar.

Comment: @Bacco, estou utilizando a versão 5.7.11

Comment: @WagnerFilho então esta solução deve funcionar. Notar que na sua query original o ON UPDATE está no local errado (deveria ser na dt_atualizacao e não na dt_cadastro. O próprio manual menciona que isto foi implementado da 5.6.5 em diante: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que vi nos comentários e respostas anteriores só vejo uma forma que ainda não tentou fazer(ou não achou a melhor). Passe o valor no `INSERT` e nos `UPDATES`

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_devedor` (`nome`, `sistema`, `id_assessoria`, `dt_cadastro`,
  `dt_atualizacao`, `situacao`) VALUES ("Maria", "SistemaXX",54, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 1);

UPDATE `tbl_devedor` SET `dt_atualizacao`= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, `nome`="Maria Fontes" WHERE  `id`=15;
```